# get records which are not present within same table against one criteria

Tags: mysql, join

I want to get IDs of users which are subscribed to one post but in some other type.

Please check the table below

Table: subscribers

```
userid  post_id  notification_made
33      780          2
35      780          2
29      780          2
33      780          1
35      780          1
```

Here in above image, While inserting the last 2 records I used insert query to add 33 and 35 with notification_made = 1. Here I want to get the IDs of users who are in this table with same post_id (780) But those are not under same notification_id (1). So I need 29 Userid which is under same post_id but not under same notification_made.

Please help !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many notification types are there? Is it just `1` and `2`?

Comment: hi Zane, there can be 5 actually. 1 to 5. Thanks

Comment: And you just want the `userid -> post_id` combinations that only have one notification made type right? Also, do you search based on a specific post_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have three parameters (two userids and a notification mode), and you want to insert, you can try:

```
INSERT INTO subscribers
SELECT DISTINCT a.userid, a.post_id, 1
FROM subscribers a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT post_id
    FROM subscribers
    WHERE userid IN (33,35) AND notification_made = 1
    GROUP BY post_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) b ON a.post_id = b.post_id
WHERE a.userid NOT IN (33,35) AND a.notification_made <> 1
```

Comment: I just want subscribe all other users who are already added somewhere under same post_id but with different notification_mode. And I will have 2 users id each time like 33 and 35 and I will have any notfication_mode such as 1 so I need all other usersID and need to add them with same notification_mode=1. If we look above table we have 29 ID which is under same post-id=780 but with different notification_mode so we need to add a new record. userid=29, post_id=780,notification_mode=1

Comment: @Zeeshan So you have three parameters: two userids and a notification mode as your parameters?

Comment: wohoo. Great, Thanks Zane. You saved my time and its works great. It added one new record with 29 userid. Hope it will work fine for all. Will check them deeply.Thanks man! :)

Comment: One quick thing, HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 Will we update this value ? What will be on place of 2? thanks

Comment: @Zeeshan, that's just the count of items in the `IN` list. What it does is it makes sure that a post_id has ***both*** of the users where notification_made = 1.